# Problema com upload de arquivos utilizando WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou com um probleminha pra enviar arquivos. Eu fiz um código funcional, no meu PC local, que enviava os arquivos à pasta do meu projeto utilizando o `move_uploaded_file`, funcionou corretamente. Só que quero aplicar esse mesmo código em meu site e não consigo de jeito nenhum. O meu site é desenvolvido em *WordPress*. Será que tem alguma coisa a ver com o *WordPress*?

```
$target_dir = 'arquivos/';
if( isset($_FILES['file']['name'])) {

  $total_files = count($_FILES['file']['name']);

  for($key = 0; $key < $total_files; $key++) {

    // Check if file is selected
    if(isset($_FILES['file']['name'][$key])
                      && $_FILES['file']['size'][$key] > 0) {

      $original_filename = $_FILES['file']['name'][$key];
      $target = $target_dir . basename($original_filename);
      $tmp  = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key];
      move_uploaded_file($tmp, $target);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Qual arquivo está esse código? Qual a rota você está utilizando? Aparece algum erro? Clique em [edit] e complemente sua pergunta, se possível.

Comment: Não gera nenhum erro. Ele simplesmente não upa os arquivos. Eu até consegui salvar no banco o nome do arquivo mas não upa os arquivos.